# continuity of identity map between different topologies

Tags: general-topology

I am independently reading through John M Lee's introduction to topological manifolds and I am stuck on two parts. Here is the question.

> For any fixed $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, let $I_{abc}$ = $\{(c,y): a < y < b\}$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all non empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $I_{abc}$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

> (1) Let $X$ = $\mathbb{R}^2$ but with the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. Determine which (if either) of the identity maps $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow X$ is continuous.
> (2) Show that $X$ is locally Euclidean (of what dimension?) and Hausdorff, but not second countable.

I have deduced that if the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is finer than the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ then, the identity map would necessarily be continuous but not vice versa. My trouble is determining which is which (that is, would the euclidean metric be finer or the other way around? What about neither?)

From this, I suspect that (1) $\implies$ (2) because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is second countable under the euclidean topology but not necessarily second countable in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. Lastly, it is intuitively obvious that $X$ is locally euclidean, because any open subset in $X$ is open in the euclidean case. However I am not sure how to phrase this concisely.

I'm clearly missing something, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A function $f$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open set $U$. If $f$ is the identity map, then $f^{-1}(U) = U$, so the questions are: is $I_{abc}$ open in the ordinary topology? If $U$ is open in the ordinary topology, for example if $U$ is of the form $U=(p,q) \times (r,s)$, is $U$ open in $X$?

Comment: What do the sets $I_{abc}$ look like?

Answer (score 1):

> From this, I suspect that (1) $\implies$ (2)

Not really. Continuous image of a second countable space does not have to be second countable. For that you additionally need the map to be open. But neither of the identities can be both continuous and open at the same time. Continuous and open bijection is a homeomorphism, and we will soon see that these spaces are not homeomorphic.

> because any open subset in $$ is open in the euclidean case.

That is not true: $I_{abc}$ is not open in the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. A subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all its point share the same first coordinate cannot be open in the Euclidean topology.

It's the other way around: every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open in $X$. That's because open rectangles $(a,b)\times (a',b')$ can be written as $\bigcup_{x\in (a,b)} I_{a'b'x}$. And open rectangles generate the Euclidean topology.

And so the identity $X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous while $\mathbb{R}^2\to X$ is not.

As for point (2) note that given a point $(x,y)\in X$ we have that $\{x\}\times \mathbb{R}$ is an open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$. That neighbourhood is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ via projection onto second coordinate. And so $X$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $1$.

Finally $X$ is not second countable. Indeed, consider $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology and let $\pi:X\to Y$ be the projection onto first coordinate. Note that it is surjective, continuous and open. But $Y$ is not second countable (a second countable discrete space has at most countable cardinality). And so $X$ cannot be as well.

In fact more can be shown. The topology on $X$ is the disjoint union topology: $X$ is homeomorphic to $\bigsqcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}$ which is homeomorphic to $\bigsqcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}$. So $X$ is just an uncountable  disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1. i would add, for the benefit of the proposer, that if $C$ is any base (basis) for $X,$ then for each $c\in \Bbb R$ there exists $f(c)\in C$ with $0\in f(c)\subseteq \{c\}\times (-1,1). $ Now $f:\Bbb R\to C$ is injective, so $C$ is uncountable.